# Pandas read_sql with parameters

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, psycopg2

Are there any examples of how to pass parameters with an SQL query in Pandas?

In particular I'm using an SQLAlchemy engine to connect to a PostgreSQL database.  So far I've found that the following works:

```py
df = psql.read_sql(('select "Timestamp","Value" from "MyTable" '
                     'where "Timestamp" BETWEEN %s AND %s'),
                   db,params=[datetime(2014,6,24,16,0),datetime(2014,6,24,17,0)],
                   index_col=['Timestamp'])
```

The Pandas documentation says that `params` can also be passed as a dict, but I can't seem to get this to work having tried for instance:

```py
df = psql.read_sql(('select "Timestamp","Value" from "MyTable" '
                     'where "Timestamp" BETWEEN :dstart AND :dfinish'),
                   db,params={"dstart":datetime(2014,6,24,16,0),"dfinish":datetime(2014,6,24,17,0)},
                   index_col=['Timestamp'])
```

What is the recommended way of running these types of queries from Pandas?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

The `read_sql` docs say this `params` argument can be a list, tuple or dict (see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html)).

To pass the values in the sql query, there are different syntaxes possible: `?`, `:1`, `:name`, `%s`, `%(name)s` (see [PEP249](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle)).
But not all of these possibilities are supported by all database drivers, **which syntax is supported depends on the driver you are using** (`psycopg2` in your case I suppose).

In your second case, when using a dict, you are using 'named arguments', and according to the `psycopg2` documentation, they support the `%(name)s` style (and so not the `:name` I suppose), see http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters.
So using that style should work:

```
df = psql.read_sql(('select "Timestamp","Value" from "MyTable" '
                     'where "Timestamp" BETWEEN %(dstart)s AND %(dfinish)s'),
                   db,params={"dstart":datetime(2014,6,24,16,0),"dfinish":datetime(2014,6,24,17,0)},
                   index_col=['Timestamp'])
```

Comment: That's very helpful - I am using psycopg2 so the '%(name)s syntax works perfectly.

Comment: We should probably mention something about that in the docstring:https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7573

Comment: This solution no longer works on Postgres - one needs to use the `:notation`, and then be sure to wrap the SQL string with `sqlalchemy.text()`

Comment: This doesn't work on SQLite with SQLAlchemy's engine.

Comment: SQLite uses the `:name` style, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute

Comment: The correct characters for the parameter style can be looked up dynamically by the way in nearly every database driver via the paramstyle attribute. This is acutally part of the PEP 249 definition.

Comment: For SQL Server use `?`. E.g., to call a stored proc with parameters, having a connection `cnn`, it is like `pd.read_sql("[dbo].[MyProc] ?,?" , cnn, params=[a,b])`

Comment: `%(name)s` still works perfectly fine in 2022 with psycopg2.

Answer (score -1):

I was having trouble passing a large number of parameters when reading from a SQLite Table. Then it turns out since you pass a string to `read_sql`, you can just use f-string. Tried the same with MSSQL pyodbc and it works as well.

For SQLite, it would look like this:

```py
# write a sample table into memory
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': pd.date_range('2020-01-17', '2020-04-24', 10), 'Value1': range(10)})
engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False)
df.to_sql('MyTable', engine);

# query the table using a query
tpl = (1, 3, 5, 8, 9)
query = f"""SELECT Timestamp, Value1 FROM MyTable WHERE Value1 IN {tpl}"""
df = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
```

If the parameters are datetimes, it's a bit more complicated but calling the datetime conversion function of the SQL dialect you're using should do the job.

```py
start, end = '2020-01-01', '2020-04-01'
query = f"""SELECT Timestamp, Value1 FROM MyTable WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN STRFTIME("{start}") AND STRFTIME("{end}")"""
df = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
```

Comment: I would say f-strings for SQL parameters are best avoided owing to the risk of SQL injection attacks, e.g. see https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/params.html#sql-injection