# pandas read_sql with parameters and wildcard operator

Tags: python, sql, pandas, wildcard

I am trying to retrieve data from sql through python with the code:

```
query = ("SELECT stuff FROM TABLE WHERE name like %%(this_name)s%")
result = pd.read_sql(query,con=cnx,params={'this_name':some_name})
```

The code above works perfectly when I don't have to pass the wildcard operator %.
However, in this case the code doesn't work. How can I pass in the query the wildcard operator? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas read\_sql with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408557/pandas-read-sql-with-parameters)

Answer (score 3):

Consider concatenating the wildcard operator, `%`, to passed in value:

```
query = ("SELECT stuff FROM TABLE WHERE name LIKE %(this_name)s") 
result = pd.read_sql(query,con=cnx, params={'this_name': '%'+ some_name +'%'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a docstring and some quotes around the like pattern. It appears you are using the pyformat paramstyle.

```
query = """SELECT stuff FROM TABLE WHERE name LIKE '%%(this_name)s%'"""
results = pd.read_sql(query, con=cnx, params={'this_name': some_name})
```