# How to format string with several nested quotes

Tags: python, sql, string

I have a SQL statement as a string in Python:

`"""SELECT * FROM table WHERE keyword = '{keyword}'""".format(keyword=term)`

Currently the above works for most terms, except those that have an apostrophe, which I understand is due to the double quote.

`term = 'cat'` is OKAY

`term = 'cat's ball'` is NOT OKAY

How can I format this string properly to allow for apostrophes in the `term` string being passed to `format`?

Comment: By not using `.format` in the first place, but rather the correct way to escape SQL given the library you're using. Show us how you're executing this SQL.

Comment: I am using it with `pandas` function `pd.read_sql`.

Comment: Then see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24418294/2482744 and [the docs of `read_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html).

Comment: Do you still want copy and paste code example, or are you good?

Comment: I'm good. Just took away `.format` and instead used the `params` arguments of `pd.read_sql()`