# MySql read_sql python query with variable @

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, variables

I am aware that queries in Python can be parameterized using either `?` or `%s` in execute query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408557/pandas-read-sql-with-parameters)

However I have some long query that would use some constant variable defined at the beginning of the query

```
Set @my_const = 'xyz';
select @my_const;
-- Query that use @my_const 40 times
select ... coalesce(field1, @my_const), case(.. then @my_const)...
```

I would like to do the least modif possible to the query from Mysql. So that instead of modifying the query to

```
pd.read_sql(select ... coalesce(field1, %s), case(.. then %s)... , [my_const, my_const, my_const, ..]
```

,I could write something along the line of the initial query. Upon trying the following, however, I am getting a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

```
query_str = "Set @null_val = \'\'; "\
    " select @null_val"
erpur_df = pd.read_sql(query_str, con = db)
```

Any idea how to use the original variable defined in Mysql query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason

```
query_str = "Set @null_val = \'\'; "\
    " select @null_val"
erpur_df = pd.read_sql(query_str, con = db)
```

throws that exception is because <strike>all you are doing is setting null_value to '' and then selecting that `''` - what exactly would you have expected that to give you?</strike> **EDIT** `read_sql` only seems to execute one query at a time, and as the first query returns no rows it results in that exception. 
If you split them in to two calls to read_sql then it will in fact return you the value of your `@null value` in the second call. Due to this behaviour `read_sql` is clearly not a good way to do this. I strongly suggest you use one of my suggestions below.

Why are you wanting to set the variable in the SQL using '@' anyway?

You could try using the `.format` style of string formatting.

Like so:

```
query_str = "select ... coalesce(field1, {c}), case(.. then {c})...".format(c=my_const)
pd.read_sql(query_str)
```

Just remember that if you do it this way and your `my_const` is a user input then you will need to sanitize it manually to prevent SQL injection.

Another possibility is using a dict of params like so:

```
query_str = "select ... coalesce(field1, %(my_const)s, case(.. then %(my_const)s)..."
pd.read_sql(query_str, params={'my_const': const_value})
```

However this is dependent on which database driver you use.

From the [pandas.read_sql docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html):

> Check your database driver documentation for which of the five syntax
>   styles, described in PEP 249’s paramstyle, is supported. Eg. for
>   psycopg2, uses %(name)s so use params={‘name’ : ‘value’}

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
You can try setting @null_val to some other string, the same error will occur. I just gave an example. Secondly, as indicated, I would love for the query string to be least modified as possible, as the query is quite lengthy; the more modif I have on the python version, the more modif I have to do every time the original query changes and I paste it to python. It seems your solution belongs to the class of using _%s_. Finally, could you elaborate more on 'sanitizing param' ?

Comment: It would help if you could explain a bit why you don't want to change the query? Doing it using paramatization in python only involves making a single query and you need it in string format to use it with `read_sql` anyway. As for sanitizing paramaters, if a parameter is being supplied by an external user then that user can supply some SQL which, without sanitizing, could perform queries such as 'DROP TABLE'. I suggest you google around 'SQL injection' to better understand the risks.

Comment: For simplicity and keeping complexity away for people maintaining it. I will not always be the one supporting it. When a person modifies the query in Mysql and tested to get what he wants, he can copy paste into python without upraising the whole world 'oh you modified something ? Here's the step you need to do in python : 1/ copy paste. 2/ @null_value replaced by {s} 3/ count the number of your {s} then create a tuple of same size, etc. I am aware of SQL injection. I was just wandering what 'sanitizing param' means

Comment: See my edit above. Abusing read_sql to do something it's not intended for is not exactly good for simplicity. You don't need a tuple of the length using either the methods I gave above. "Your long query".format(c=value) is clear, easy, and works with read_sql. As for copying from MySQL it would be an easy find/replace of @my_const for {c}.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take your advice. Nevertheless upon trying I came across 2 issues. Consider query_str = " select * from my_table a where my_column like {v_like} ".format(v_like=my_var) 1. try with my_var = '%rie' or '''%rie''' (3 single quotes) or " '%rie' ", only in the last one will my quote be kept and not second. Is it normal ? 2. With 3rd option I get my query well as select * from my_table a where my_column like '%rie' . Yet read_sql failed with "not all arguments converted during string formatting".Apparently it thinks %rie is another argument. Escaping with '%%rie' also fail.Any idea

Comment: Please ignore my 2nd point. I found the error. However still wondering about the 1st point where escaping with ''' does not work

Comment: Yes, that is expected string quoting behaviour in Python.

Comment: I meant, even after escaping ''' (3 single quotes), the single quote is lost

Comment: How exactly are you typing it out with triple quotes? If you are doing '''%rie''' then of course no quotes are included. If you are doing ''''%rie'''' then you'll get a SyntaxError, if you do '''"%rie"''' or """'%rie'""" then you'll get either a double quoted or single-quoted %rie inserted in to the string

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. ' ' is used to escape ' in python string. And yet my_var = '''%rie'''
query_str = " select * from my_table a where my_column like {v_like} ".format(v_like=my_var)
or my_var = '%rie'
query_str = " select * from my_table a where my_column like {v_like} ".format(v_like=my_var) produce the same thing, without quote around %rie

Comment: Triple-quoting (either using " or ') is a special case in Python which is used for multi-line strings. Using ''' or just ' in this case are basically identical. If you want to escape quotes in a string use the opposite quoting style for the whole string (i.e. use double quotes inside single quotes or vice versa) OR you have to use \ to escape the.