# How to pass a list of dates as VALUES into read_spl using parameter substitution?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have an sqlite database and there's a table called `cached_dates` which simply has a row for each date, where the date is type `text` and looks like `YYYY-MM-DD`.

I also have a list of dates in the same string format and I want to know which dates in that last are not in the `cached_dates` table.

I can't figure out how to encode the string in a way that I can pass it into the pandas `read_sql` function using parameter substitution.

I can do it using string formatting but I know that's susceptible to injection attacks so I'd like to do it properly but I can figure out the syntax. Here's what I'm doing now:

Create the table:

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cached_dates (date text NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);`

Insert something into the table:

`insert into cached_dates values('2018-01-03');`

This is the query I want to make:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    VALUES('2018-01-01'),('2018-01-02'),('2018-01-03'),('2018-01-04'),('2018-01-05')
)
EXCEPT
SELECT date FROM cached_dates;
```

This is the python code I'm using:

```
date_list = ['2018-01-01','2018-01-02','2018-01-03','2018-01-04','2018-01-05']

# Convert to string that can be passed to VALUES
dates_str = ''
for date in date_list:
    dates_str = dates_str + "('{}'),".format(date)
dates_str = dates_str[:-1]

sql = ( 'SELECT * '
        'FROM ' 
        '('
        'VALUES {}'
        ') '
        'EXCEPT '
        'SELECT date FROM cached_dates;').format(dates_str)

df = pd.read_sql(sql, self._conn)
```

I'd like to use the `params` parameter of `read_sql` but I couldn't get that to work. Can someone please show me how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
sql = ( 'SELECT * '
        'FROM ' 
        '('
        'VALUES %(date_str)s'
        ') '
        'EXCEPT '
        'SELECT date FROM cached_dates;')

df = pd.read_sql(sql, self._conn, params = {"date_str" : dates_str })
```

You can take reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408557/pandas-read-sql-with-parameters)

Comment: Hmmm.. That gives me an error too... `Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM (VALUES %(date_str)s) EXCEPT SELECT date FROM cached_dates;': near "%": syntax error`.