# Efficient way to pass this variable multiple times

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm using Pyodbc in Python to run some SQL queries. What I'm working with is actually longer than this, but this example captures what I'm trying to do:

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(...)
cursor = connection.cursor(...)

dte = '2018-10-24'

#note the placeholders '{}'
query = """select invoice_id
    into #output 
    from table1 with (nolock) 
    where system_id = 'PrimaryColor' 
    and posting_date = '{}' 

    insert into #output
    select invoice_id
    from table2 with (nolock)
    where system_id = 'PrimaryColor'
    and posting_date = '{}'"""

#this is where I need help as explained below
cursor.execute(query.format(dte, dte))

output = pd.read_sql("""select *
                 from #output"""
                 , connection)
```

In the above, since there are only two `'{}'`, I'm passing `dte` to `query.format()` twice. However, in the more complicated version I'm working with, I have 19 `'{}'`, so I'd imagine this means I need to pass '`dte'` to `'query.format{}'` 19 times. I tried passing this as a list, but it didn't work. Do I really need to write out the variable 19 times when passing it to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments, [pandas.read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) has a params argument which prevent from sql injection.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408557/pandas-read-sql-with-parameters) to understand how to use it depending on the database.

[Pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor) has the same parameter on the execute method.

> ```
> # standard 
> cursor.execute("select a from tbl where b=? and c=?", (x, y))
>
> # pyodbc extension 
> cursor.execute("select a from tbl where b=? and c=?", x, y)
> ```

---

To answer to the initial question, even if it is bad practice for building SQL queries :

> Do I really need to write out the variable 19 times when passing it to the function?

Of course you don't :

```
query = """select invoice_id
into #output 
from table1 with (nolock) 
where system_id = 'PrimaryColor' 
and posting_date = '{dte}' 

insert into #output
select invoice_id
from table2 with (nolock)
where system_id = 'PrimaryColor'
and posting_date = '{dte}'""".format(**{'dte': dte})
```

or :

```
query = """select invoice_id
into #output 
from table1 with (nolock) 
where system_id = 'PrimaryColor' 
and posting_date = '{0}' 

insert into #output
select invoice_id
from table2 with (nolock)
where system_id = 'PrimaryColor'
and posting_date = '{0}'""".format(dte)
```

[Python 3.6+](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) :

```
query = f"""select invoice_id
into #output 
from table1 with (nolock) 
where system_id = 'PrimaryColor' 
and posting_date = '{dte}' 

insert into #output
select invoice_id
from table2 with (nolock)
where system_id = 'PrimaryColor'
and posting_date = '{dte}'"""
```

Note the usage of f before """ ... """

Comment: @roganjosh thanks, i mixed up because he uses pandas as well. Edited

Comment: Thank you! This did it!

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a `UNION ALL` query to avoid the temp table needs and [parameterization](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Getting-started) where you set qmark placeholders and in a subsequent step bind values to them. And being the same value multiply the parameter list/tuple by needed number:

```
dte = '2018-10-24'

# NOTE THE QMARK PLACEHOLDERS
query = """select invoice_id    
           from table1 with (nolock) 
           where system_id = 'PrimaryColor' 
             and posting_date = ? 

           union all

           select invoice_id
           from table2 with (nolock)
           where system_id = 'PrimaryColor'
             and posting_date = ?"""

output = pd.read_sql(query, connection, params=(dte,)*2)
```