# Usage error in pandas.read_sql with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

Consider you have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM foo_schema.run_info WHERE id=:param order by run_id desc", s.bind, **{'param':5})
```

Whereas `s.bind` is `sqlchemy`'s engine object.

I get the following error:

```
{TypeError}read_sql() got an unexpected argument 'param'
```

what is wrong with my function call?

Comment: What is `{'param':5}` supposed to be?

Comment: Just simple example to parameter passing to the query, we have placeholder there `WHERE id=:param`, so this need to be parsed to `WHERE id=5` in this case

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408557/pandas-read-sql-with-parameters

Comment: @IljaEverilä: I alraedy saw this. Any idea, why I still get error even after trying `coldspeed`'s suggested answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html),

> ```
> pd.read_sql?
> ...
> params : list, tuple or dict, optional, default: None
> ```

What you're doing is unpacking the dictionary, so it is passed as a keyword argument. See [Understanding kwargs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python) for more information.

The correct way to pass parameters is:

```
pd.read_sql(... params={'param':5})
```

---

As @Ilja Everilä expertly mentioned, you should wrap your query inside a call to `text` in order to have the parameter syntax correctly parsed.

```
from sqlalchemy import text
pd.read_sql(text(query), s.bind, params={'param':5})
```

Comment: I did it but got:   `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version `for the right syntax to use near ':param order by run_id desc' at line 1") `

Comment: The colon-style named parameter is something that not many DB-API drivers support (though it is [part of the spec](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle)), but if you've had a look at SQLA docs you might've picked it up. It's used by the SQLA `text()` construct to provide DB-API agnostic named parameter handling. So the fix is to wrap `query` in a call to `text()` before passing to `read_sql()`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Want to take this one? I'll be happy to delete.

Comment: Nah, just amend with `text(query)` and that's that :)