# Loop SQL Query Over Dictionary

Tags: python, sql, loops, amazon-redshift

I have a SQL query that uses the first and the last day of the calendar months to generate a subset of data for a given month. I have been trying to figure out how to loop it for a number of months  - i have two lists (one for first and another for last days), two tuples (same), and a dictionary (first and last are keys and values) with all these dates - and store all results in one dataframe  and i am struggling very bad.

I can do loop and get all the data if i am only using one list or tuple - then i can loop through it and get all the data. if i try to use two, it simply does not work. Is there a way to do what I am trying to do?

```
fd=['2018-05-01','2018-06-01','2018-07-01']
```

```
ld=['2018-05-31','2018-06-30','2018-07-31']
my_dict=dict(zip(fd, ld))
```

```
data_check=pd.DataFrame()

fd_d=','.join(my_dict.keys())
ed_d=','.join(['%%(%s)s' % x for x in my_dict])

query= """

SELECT count(distinct ids),first_date, last_date  from table1
where first_date=%s and last_date =%s
group by 2,3
"""
for x in my_dict:
    df=pd.read_sql(query% (fd_d,ed_d),my_dict)
    data_check=data_check.append(df)
```

Comment: added - redshift. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In general, please heed three best practices:

1. Avoid the [quadratic copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489724/1422451) of using `DataFrame.append` in a loop. Instead, build a list of data frames to be concatenated once outside the loop.
2. Use parameterization and not string concatenation which is supported with pandas [`read_sql`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24418294/1422451). This avoids the need to string format and punctuate with quotes.
3. Discontinue using the modulo operator, `%`, for string concatenation as it is [de-emphasised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452357/1422451) (not officially deprecated). Instead, use the superior [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Specifically, for your needs iterate elementwise between two lists using `zip` without layering it in a dictionary:

```
query= """SELECT count(distinct ids), first_date, last_date 
          FROM table1 
          WHERE first_date = %s and last_date = %s 
          GROUP BY 2, 3""" 

df_list = []
for f, l in zip(fd, ld): 
   df = pd.read_sql(query, conn, params=[f, l]) 
   df_list.append(df)

final_df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

---

Alternatively, avoid the loop and parameters by aggregating on first and last of days of every month in table:

```
query= """SELECT count(distinct ids), first_date, last_date 
          FROM table1 
          WHERE DATE_PART(d, first_date) = 1
            AND last_date = LAST_DAY(first_date)
          GROUP BY 2, 3
          ORDER BY 2, 3""" 

final_df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```