# What is the correct way of comparing SQL datetime objects and Python datetime objects in a query?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, datetime, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Notebooks and have connected my PostreSQL database like so:

```
%load_ext sql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
```

I am using Python's `datetime` and the `pytz` library to create a timezone **aware** datetime object:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import pytz
from pytz import timezone

eastern = timezone('EST')

now = dt.datetime.now()
start = dt.datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day - 2, now.hour, now.minute, tzinfo=eastern)
```

Now when I am trying to make an SQL query, I do something like this to create a pandas DataFrame:

```
events_query = pd.read_sql(
    """\
        SELECT start_time,
        end_time,
        FROM events 
        WHERE room_id=2 
        AND deleted=false
        AND start_time < {}
        limit 3
    """.format(start), engine)
```

However, on the line `start_time < {}`, I get this error:

```
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "14"
LINE 10:         and start_time < 2020-06-16 14:07:00-05:00
```

However, when I check the types and comparison values of the SQL start_time datatime object and my created Python datetime object, the comparison works normally (if I omit the `start_time < {}` comparison):

```
test = events_query['start_time'].values[0]
print(test)
print(start)
print(test > start)
```

This will print out:

```
2038-11-25 12:00:00-05:00
2020-06-16 14:07:00-05:00
True
```

**What I have tried alternatively**
Instead of using `.format()` notation, I have also tried to use Python f-strings to insert the `start` variable, as well as using the % operator formatting. The error was the same for comparing `start_time` with a variable.

Sorry, this is my second time ever posting on SO, let me know if I formatted my question correctly.

Comment: The correct way is likely to _not_ use string formatting.. The error is because the literal SQL supplied is invalid (eg. log the out of the result of `"..".format(..)`). Does PD have a notion of "place holders"?

Comment: Indeed, it does. See the `params` of [read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) and refer to the Pg driver documentation. Internally, Pg should be able to coerce the ISO date with offset (although the rules for such depend on the type of `start` column, etc).

Comment: @user2864740 wow, thank you so much! Worked perfectly. After your answer, I found exactly what I needed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408557/pandas-read-sql-with-parameters).