# How to Pass a Variable from Python to SQL script

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's my Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2

# connect to db
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="localhost",
    database="postgres",
    user="postgres",
    port= "5432",
    password="example")

# read in the sql file
fd = open('SQL/example.sql', 'r')
sqlFile = fd.read()
fd.close()

# get query
mydate = '1/1/2021'
data = pd.read_sql(sqlFile, conn)
```

Here's my SQL script:

```
select *
from myschema.table
where date = $mydate
```

I want to pass my Python variable "mydate" to SQL. So when I run SQL, it would show the date stored in the variable as such. i.e. The  string sqlFile would actually show:

```
select *
from myschema.table
where date = '1/1/2021'
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas read\_sql with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408557/pandas-read-sql-with-parameters)

Comment: Do `data = pd.read_sql(sqlFile, conn, params={"mydate": mydate})`, and change your files to use format: i.e. `where date = %(mydate)s`