# Use pandas list to filter data using postgresql query

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I already referred these posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408557/pandas-read-sql-with-parameters), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283645/python-list-in-sql-query-as-parameter). Am not sure whether I am using the suggestions from these posts incorrectly.

Basically, I would like to use my pandas list in a postgresql query (written in Jupyter notebook)

```
id_list = [1,2,3,4]
```

I would like to use my `id_list` in the below query. I tried the below 2 options

**option-1**

```
df_q = pd.read_sql('select * from tablea where subject_id in {id_list}', con=conn)
```

**option-2**

```
cur.execute("select * from tablea where subject_id in %s", id_list)
```

Can experts here help me with the solution on how to use the python variables directly in the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to handle an `IN` clause is by building the placeholder clause separately, then using parameter substitution to bind the list elements to the query:

```py
sql = "select * from tablea where subject_id in ({})"
# Create a string like "%s, %s, %s" with one "%s" per list element
placeholders = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(id_list))
sql = sql.format(placeholders)
# Use parameter substitution to bind values to the query
cur.execute(sql, id_list)
```

Using string formatting or concatenation, including f-strings, may cause errors if values are incorrectly escaped, or in the worst case expose your database to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: What is the result of `print(cur.mogrify(sql, id_list))`?

Comment: I fixed it. It was an unrelated issue. May I know what does `mogrify` stand for?

Comment: It prints the query that will be sent to the database https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.mogrify (assuming that your are using psycopg2, which I should checked :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a variable inside string in python you just want to add `f` at the start of the string like that

`df_q = pd.read_sql(f'select * from tablea where subject_id in {id_list}', con=conn)`

This will get translated to
`'select * from tablea where subject_id in [1, 3, 4]'`

Comment: However, Postgresql does not use `[` to express lists. You might want to convert list to tuple as it use `(`.

```df_q = pd.read_sql(f'select * from tablea where subject_id in {tuple(id_list)}', con=conn)```

Comment: Using string formatting to bind values to SQL queries is error-prone and a security risk.  Please don;t do it.