# Use multiple pandas list in postgresql query to filter data

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, dataframe, psycopg2

I already referred this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68066426/use-pandas-list-to-filter-data-using-postgresql-query) and trying to extend it to work for multiple lists

Basically, I would like to use multiple pandas list in a postgresql query (written in Jupyter notebook)

```
subj_list = [1,2,3,4]
class_list = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
```

I would like to both my lists in the below query. I tried the below

```
sql = "select * from tablea where subject_id in ({}) and class_id in ({})"
sub_ids = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(subj_list))
class_ids = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(class_list))
sql = sql.format(sub_ids ,class_ids )
cur.execute(sql,subj_list,class_list)
```

I get an error as shown below

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 cur.execute(sql,subj_list,class_list)
>
> TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

I tried to extend [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68066426/use-pandas-list-to-filter-data-using-postgresql-query) for multiple lists but it doesn't seem to work.

Might be am using it incorrectly. Can help me with this?

Can experts here help me with the solution on how to use the multiple python list variables directly in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cursor.execute` expects it's second argument to be a sequence with one element per value placeholder.  To satisfy this requirement, make a new list by adding both lists together (or extending the first with the second).

```py
all_values = subj_list + class_list
print(cur.mogrify(sql, all_values))
```

gives

```
b'select * from tablea where subject_id in (1, 2, 3, 4) and class_id in (4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)'
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use tuple instead of list , you can easily do this :

```
subj_list = (1,2,3,4)
class_list = (4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)

sql = "select * from tablea where subject_id in {} and class_id in {}"
cur.execute(sql,subj_list,class_list)
```