# Read SQL query into pandas dataframe and replace string in query

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pandas

I'm querying my SSMS database from pandas and the query I have is pretty huge, I've saved it locally and want to read that query as a pandas dataframe and also there is a date string that I have in the query, I want to replace that datestring with a date that I've already assigned in pandas. For reference sake I'll shorten the query.

I'm currently following below:

```
query = """SELECT * FROM table where date > 'date_string' """

query_result = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```

Instead of writing select * ... in pandas I've saved my query locally. I want pandas to read that query. And also replace **date_string** with **startDate_sql**

My date_string keeps changing as I'm looping through a list of dates.

The pandas code would look like

```
query = 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Python\Open Source\query.sql'
query.replace(date_string, startDate_sql)
query_result = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```

In this way I'm not writing my query in pandas as it is a huge query and consumes lot of space.

Can someone please tell me how to solve this and what is the correct syntax?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reading a file in Python

Here's how to read in a text file in Python.

```py
query_filename = 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Python\Open Source\query.sql'
# 'rt' means open for reading, in text mode
with open(query_filename, 'rt') as f:
    # read the query_filename file into a variable named query
    query = f.read()
# replace the literal string 'date_string' with the contents of the variable startDate_sql
query = query.replace('date_string', startDate_sql)
# get dataframe from database
query_result = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```

### Using parameterized queries

You should probably avoid string replacement to construct queries, because it suffers from [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). Parameterized queries avoid this problem. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24418294/530160) of how to use query parameterization with Pandas.