# how to input a tuple inside the python sql IN operator

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a query which takes some input which will be used in `IN` operator of sql.
Since `IN` operator takes a `()` which is a tuple in python, I am unable to give the input to the query as a tuple because my input tuple is like ->  `(296,)`. In this, I am not sure how to deal with the `,` inside the tuple because it causing an error.

my data for reference: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m4RoYpdKQXY5KcVgrfmApq/0

My query with python is as follow:

```
    query = '''
      SELECT timestamp as timestamp,
      id ,
      users
      FROM rc 
      WHERE  timestamp='{}' and id IN {}
     
    '''.format(timestamp, id_tuple)

    df = pd.read_sql(query, con=sql.engine)
```

Comment: `'''.format(timestamp, '(' + ','.join(id_tuple) + ')')`

Comment: better to use parameters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408557/pandas-read-sql-with-parameters

Comment: my input tuple has`int`.

Comment: `'''.format(timestamp, '(' + ','.join(id_tuple) + ')')` -> this gives `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found`

Comment: `'''.format(timestamp, '(' + ','.join(map(str, id_tuple)) + ')')`

Comment: As a generic approach, use `= any` instead of `in`. `and id = any(string_to_array('{}', ',')::integer[])` and pass the argument as a comma-separated list.