# How to call Microsoft SQL Server Stored Procedure from within Python using SQL Alchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, pandas, stored-procedures, sqlalchemy

I would like to execute a Stored Procedure residing on Microsoft SQL Server using Python and SQL Alchemy.

So far I am able to connect to Microsoft SQL Server, run simple select query, assign it to a Panda Data Frame and save it to an csv file using the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
Server='Jaar'
Database='M'
Driver='ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
Database_Con = f'mssql://@{Server}/{Database}?driver={Driver}'
engine=create_engine(Database_Con)
con = engine.connect()
df=pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM [M].[Dim].[Accounts_t]",con)
```

However, I've tried unsuccessfully to do the same with a SP which takes two parameters

Furthermore, I have not been able to get this example to work:
https://sql-query.dev/articles/1767

And haven't found much in the SQL Alchemy documentation that can help me.

Thanks

The SP that I want to execute is below:

```
USE [M]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [Reporting].[Finance_Payments_Mvmts_sp]
        @PeriodStart = 202212,
        @PeriodEnd = 202310

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Comment: I believe you can just put your exec statement into the `read_sql_query` call. Make sure to parameterize your query though instead of directly interpolating your parameter values. See if this helps you with that: [Pandas read_sql with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408557/pandas-read-sql-with-parameters)

Comment: @Xedni This doesn't work at all. I tried it with a SP with no parameters. I guess it's not expecting the word EXEC before the Stored Procedure

Comment: You've mentioned it doesn't work; can you expand on that? Are you getting an error message? Is the result set empty?

Comment: I don't think SQLAlchemy is intended to work with multiple result sets directly (I'm assuming here your stored procedure returns a result set of its own and then selecting `@return_value` like that will be a second seperate result set). Have you considered using SQLAlchemy's `engine.raw_connection()` to access [multiple result sets](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#multiple-result-sets)?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I should add that I don't need the return value actually. I just need to execute the SP like this: EXEC [Reporting].[Finance_Payments_Mvmts_sp] PeriodStart = 202212, PeriodEnd = 202310 i.e. with the two parameters

Comment: @Xedni I cannot remember the exact error but I think it was to do with not being able to use EXEC in read_sql_query method. It doesn't get to the stage where it either returns or does not return a record set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't work with SQL Alchemy and SQL Server so I finally found another Python module for accessing SQL Server called pymssql:

```
import pymssql
import pandas as pd
conn = pymssql.connect(server = 'Jaar', database = 'M')
cursor = conn.cursor(as_dict=True)
PeriodStart = 202212
PeriodEnd = 202310
cursor.callproc('[Reporting].[Finance_Payments_Mvmts_sp]', (PeriodStart, PeriodEnd))
(202212, 202310)
rows = []
for row in cursor:
    rows.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
print(df)

df.to_csv("TestOutput.csv")
```

Does what I need it to do which is to run a SQL Server Stored Procedure with input parameters

https://pypi.org/project/pymssql/