# SQLite3 read issue with multiple simultaneous access to db

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am having some trouble with data reads with my SQLite3 database.

Context:
I have built a python program that relies on two scripts running in parallel:

- Script1: Reads on an ongoing basis (on a time.sleep(30)) messages streamed from an MQTT broker and writes some data in table1 of my SQLite database (let's call it database1).
- Script2: Has a number of processes which rely on access to database1. Whilst most processes involve reading/writing on other tables of database1, one process that has sporadic issues is the one that relies on reading table1 of database1 whilst script1 is running. The issue being that the reading of table1 from script2 may be skipped altogether. Script2 is being run for testing in a time.sleep(120), but when its proven to work reliably, it will go down to time.sleep(300)

From a lot of googling/reading forum threads and SQLite documentation, I believe this is due to the fact that whilst script1 writes into table1 of database1, the table1 becomes blocked of access. This becomes a problem when the process of script2 coincides with the write of script1 on the same database1 table1. I note that when I only run script2 (and do not execute script1), I never have this issue (i.e. all reads of table1 from script2 are never skipped), and everything process run smoothly.

I have tried a number of things including adding a timeout to my db connection and a pragma busy timeout (snippet bellow). Both timeouts have been applied to all the db functions I used in the two scripts but the results are the same.

Read function used from script2:

```
def db_read_function(param1,param2,param3):
    con=None
    temp_df='null'
    db=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), './database1.db')
    try:
        con=sqlite3.connect(db, timeout=20) #Increase timeout from default 5sec.
        c = con.cursor()
        c.execute('''pragma busy_timeout=10000''') #Busy timeout changed to 10s (in ms)
        temp_df = pd.read_sql(
            '''SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE device_id='%s' AND
            payload_timestamp_utc=(SELECT MAX(payload_timestamp_utc) from table1 WHERE device_id='%s')
            AND start_time_utc<'%s' AND end_time_utc>'%s'
            order by start_time_utc asc '''
            % (param1,param1,param3,param2), con)
        con.close()
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    return temp_df
```

Write function used from script 1:

```
def db_insert_function(row):
    con=None
    db=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), './database1.db')
    try:
        con=sqlite3.connect(db, timeout=20)
        c = con.cursor()
        c.execute('''pragma busy_timeout=10000''')  # Busy timeout changed to 10s (in ms)
        sql = '''INSERT INTO table1(site_name,payload_timestamp_utc,device_id,start_time_utc,end_time_utc,
        value) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?) '''
        c = con.cursor()
        c.execute(sql, row)
        con.commit()
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    return c.lastrowid
```

Schema used when creating the table1:

```
c.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1
        ([id] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
        [site_name] TEXT,
        [payload_timestamp_utc] TEXT,
        [device_id] TEXT,
        [start_time_utc] TEXT,
        [end_time_utc] TEXT,
        [value] TEXT)
        ''')
```

Further to reading https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5, it seems a path forward would be to use sqlite3_busy_handler() or sqlite3_busy_timeout() to run a test if the table is in fact busy so that it can wait and re-try (by pausing the process of script1 that relies on table1 reads when busy for a few seconds ), but I can't manage to get it to work or find any application example online.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: it looks like a case of concurrent access issues. have you considered adding more busy handlers?

Comment: Thanks for the response @jeffreyohene. How does one do this? As I mentioned on the bottom part of the post, I read the doco on sqlite3_busy_handler() but unsure how to implement it. I am quite new to python/SQLite3.

Comment: Without seeing your code, or at least the SQL statements which are being executed, there isn't much we can do. "*The issue being that the reading of table1 from script2 may be skipped altogether.*" If the query failed, there should be an error. Or do you mean the read returned no results?

Comment: To bring the issue to a single point: SQLite is not designed for concurrent access. It just has very limited support for it. If you need real concurrency consider to use a DB server.

Comment: @KlausD. I believe [concurrency got much better in SQLite 3](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html), especially for such a simple case as this. I doubt SQLite is at fault.

Comment: @Schwern, query returns a correct dataframe all the time when I either only run script2 or use the exact same SQL statement using DB Browser via the SQL query interface. When I run script1+Script2, that SQL statement generated from script2 seem to work only 50% of the time (by returning an empty dataframe when it doesnt work and a correct dataframe when it does work).

Comment: When I sense check the times that it "didn't work" (i.e. returned an empty dataframe), I ran the exact same query using DB Browser's SQL interface and it returns valid data (as it does when it "works").

Comment: @Flamby We need to see the queries being run. Also some idea of how much data you're writing.

Comment: @Schwern I edited the post with the query being run from script 2. script 1 writes every 2mins on average into table1 around 300 new rows.

Comment: @Schwern also, script 2 is being run for testing in a time.sleep(120), but when its proven to work reliably, it will go down to time.sleep(300). Script 1 will remain at time.sleep(30) to ensure I don't miss any messages on the MQTT broker.

Comment: @Flamby Please post **all** the queries being run on the database. **Especially** the writes. Ideally, [we need enough to reproduce your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also please show us your schema and indexes. Your read query might be very expensive if the table is large and unindexed. If it isn't indexed it might be doing a full table scan which might be blocking while the table is being written to. There's just too little information.

Comment: @Schwern details added as requested. These are the queries being run on that table. There is a very similar query being read and written from another table in the same database (both read/written from script 2) but they never fail. Please let me know if you need anything else. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Flamby I see no indexes. Without indexes, that read query has to read the whole table making it potentially slow and expensive and vulnerable to locks. If the write locks any rows the read might have to wait. The writing can also be done more efficiently. 1) How large is that table? 2) How many rows are you inserting at a time? 3) Are you doing all those inserts in one transaction? (If so, locks will be held for the whole transaction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bunch of potential performance problems which could be causing your issue(s). You shouldn't need to add special busy timeouts, you can just make things faster. *A lot* faster.

## Performance issues.

### Add indexes.

Your table lacks indexes. Indexes are what make SQL databases perform well. Without indexes, SQLite has to read the whole table for every query. With indexes, reads can be almost instantaneous. Indexes are what let SQL databases handle millions and billions of rows gracefully.

If your table is large that read query (actually two queries because of the subquery) could get **very** expensive. While that read is happening, you can't write (though see the node about WAL mode below).

Looking at your query...

```
select * 
from table1
where device_id='%s'
  and payload_timestamp_utc=(
        select max(payload_timestamp_utc)
        from table1
        where device_id='%s'
  )
  and start_time_utc < '%s' and end_time_utc > '%s'
order by start_time_utc asc
```

A compound index on `(device_id, payload_timestamp_utc)` will likely speed up this query *significantly*. The `select max...` subquery will be almost instantaneous. The outer query will be able to use the index to find all rows with that device_id and timestamp, there should only be a handful or just one, and will only have to search and order that handful of rows.

See [Use The Index, Luke](https://use-the-index-luke.com/) and [W3Schools SQL Index](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_ref_index.asp).

The query could also potentially be written in a more efficient way, but we'd need to know more detail. The index should do it.

### Try WAL mode.

By default, SQLite3 locks the whole database file. Reading locks in *shared* mode; there can be any number of readers, but no writers. Writing locks in *exclusive* mode; there can only be one writer, and no readers.

There's also [WAL (Write-Ahead Log) mode](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html). This is potentially much faster if you're writing a lot. And in WAL mode, readers and writers don't block each other. Readers can read while the writes are happening, and writes can write while reads are happening.

WAL mode is not a magic bullet, but it could help significantly.

### Reuse the same database connection.

Opening a connection for every query is potentially expensive if you're running a lot of queries.

Open a database connection *once* per process (or thread) and reuse it.

### Insert in batches.

If you're inserting a lot of rows, it can get expensive to do one insert for each row. Instead, insert in bulk.

```
insert into some_table values
  (?,?,?,?,?,?),
  (?,?,?,?,?,?),
  (?,?,?,?,?,?),
  ...
  (?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

While the insert is happening, nothing else can use the database (* except in WAL mode). Don't insert too many at a time, or hold the transaction open too long. Ideally each insert only lasts for a second or two at most, that way reads can slip in between the inserts.

Start with a max of 1000 in one insert statement and adjust. If you have thousands of rows to insert, you'll have to loop and insert in batches.

You may wish to use a dedicated SQL framework such as [SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/index.html) to help writing SQL for you.

## Free advice.

None of the read is causing your problem, but this is just extra coding advice.

### Store time as an integer.

[SQLite doesn't have a built in timestamp type](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html), but we can do better than text. Since all your timestamps are in UTC anyway, store them as integers. This will use less space, and be faster to read and compare.

Use [`unixepoch`](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to convert your text timestamps to seconds. If they need higher precision, use the `subsecond` modifier and store the time in milliseconds.

### ***NEVER*** use string concatenation for query parameters.

Adding parameters to a query using string concatenation invites [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) to your database. These are [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Instead, [use the parameters provided by pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408557/pandas-read-sql-with-parameters).

### Use `None` not `"null"`.

Most languages have a special value for "null". [In Python it is `None`](https://realpython.com/null-in-python/). So `temp_df = None` and then check for `None`.

### Let the caller handle the exception.

It's very tempting to deal with exceptions by catching and printing them and then returning a flag, but this defeats the point of exceptions. Exceptions are there to 1) provide the caller with context about what went wrong, 2) let the exception be handled as the caller sees fit, and 3) forces the caller to handle the exception.

Remove the exception handler from the function and let the caller handle the exception as they see fit. Then the caller can't forget to check for an error (if they do, the whole program halts), the caller has the full exception to examine so they can decide what to do, and the caller knows best what should be done in case a query fails.

Comment: Hi Schwern, sorry for the delay in reverting back, just been off for a few days. Thanks a lot for the above response. Lots to unpack for me as a beginner but I will dissect each comment and review all associated links. I will provide some feedback in the coming day(s) on how the implementation of your suggestions went.

Comment: @Flamby I'm interested to know how it goes. Good luck.

Comment: Well, I'm a bit lost for words. I have implemented just about all of the above suggestions (which no doubt are improving my code A LOT), but have unfortunately not solved my problem. I have added the compound index suggested, activated WAL mode, Reused the same db connection and batched the several writes together (which drastically shorten the writing process so amazing result!) but I still periodically have an empty df as a result of the db_read_function above (when it des not return empty when doing the same query from DB Browser using the SQL interface.).

Comment: I also added a delete rows section at the end of the script1 loop and script2 loop to ensure each respective table remain small by deleting data older than 2hrs old (but have not used vacuum). Still the sporadic issue persists.

Comment: Schwern, the issue seems to have resolved itself! I deleted the db and re-created it (still applying all of the above advice) and I no longer have the conflict. I will close this out. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Flamby Mysterious. Glad you got it working and learned some performance tuning.

Answer (score 0):

without a reproducible issue, it is quite hard to give a definite answer. however, test this to see if it resolves your issue. i included a custom_busy_handler function that will return a callback function for the busy handler and an inner_callback that is the actual callback that will be called when SQLite encounters a busy condition.

it sleeps for a specified timeout and returns True to retry or False to give up. db_function1 was modified to set the custom busy handler using con.set_busy_handler(custom_busy_handler(retries, timeout)). play around with the retries and timeout arguments to see how it works in your individual case

```
def custom_busy_handler(retries, timeout):
    def inner_callback(tries):
        if tries >= retries:
            return False  # Give up if retries exceed a certain limit
        time.sleep(timeout)
        return True

    return inner_callback

def db_function1(param1, param2, param3, retries=5, timeout=1):
    con = None
    temp_df = 'null'
    db = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), './database1.db')
    try:
        con = sqlite3.connect(db, timeout=20)  # Increase timeout from default 5sec.
        con.execute('''pragma busy_timeout=10000''')  # Busy timeout changed to 10s (in ms)

        # Set up a custom busy handler
        con.create_function("busy_handler", 2, custom_busy_handler(retries, timeout))

        temp_df = pd.read_sql(
            '''SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ...''',
            % (param1, param2, param3), con)
        con.close()
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    return temp_df

# Example of using db_function1 with custom busy handler
result = db_function1("value1", "value2", "value3", retries=5, timeout=1)
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, will give it a try and report back.

Comment: Returns a traceback "AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'set_busy_handler'"

Comment: i made an edit. for the busy handler use: con.create_function("busy_handler", 2, custom_busy_handler(retries, timeout))

Comment: Thanks, it fixes the traceback. Running both scripts for a few moments and will revert back.

Comment: Still having the sporadic issue. It's driving me nuts! I can't get an actual error/traceback code when the script2 read of table1 returns nothing (i.e. empty dataframe). When I log into the db using DB Browser and do the exact same SQL search for the exact same query/parameter that had returned nothing via script2, the read returns a value every time..

Comment: can you debug to see if the sql statement actually works? try to run a query outside the function scope and assign it to a variable and check to see if some data is actually returned

Comment: Not sure I quite understand how to do that but the SQL statement works fine when I either only run script2 or use the exact same SQL statement using DB Browser via the SQL query interface. When I run script1+Script2, that SQL statement generated from script2 seem to work only 50% of the time.

Comment: To be clear, the other 50% of time when it "doesn't work", it returns an empty dataframe. But I know it should not return an empty dataframe (as confirmed when doing the same query on the same dataset using DB Browser)

Answer (score 0):

To update the community, deleting the database and recreating it whilst applying some of the above advices resolved my issue.

To provide a bit more details on the advices @Schwern provided, and for the more beginner crowd like me, here are the codes additions that improved my overall script performance:

**The compound index on table1 was added by:**

```
c.execute('''
        CREATE INDEX idx_id
        ON dispatch_signals (device_id, payload_timestamp_utc)
        ''')
```

A great read on compound indexes (in addition to the links provided) is this [link](https://www.scaler.com/topics/sql/composite-index-in-sql/).

**For WAL mode activation, I used:**

```
con.execute('''pragma journal_mode=WAL''')
```

**For reuse of database connection and query batching, script 1 function used was updated to:**

```
def db_insert_function(rows):
    con=None
    db=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), './database1.db')
    try:
        con=sqlite3.connect(db, timeout=20)
        c = con.cursor()
        c.execute('''pragma busy_timeout=10000''')
        sql = '''INSERT INTO table1(site_name,payload_timestamp_utc,device_id,start_time_utc,end_time_utc,
        value) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?) '''
        c = con.cursor()
        c.executemany(sql, rows)
        con.commit()
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    return c.lastrowid
```

For the use of the function in the script, I batched each row into a list (named 'rows') and passed it with db_insert_function(rows). This drastically reduced the time I took to input these 2-300 rows on each script loop.

If you have questions feel free to comment on the below, happpy to share my experience with this.

Also a big thank you to @jeffreyohene, whilst his answer worked on creating a busy handler, it wasn't what was causing my issue.